# An Understanding of Dominated Convergence theorem

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I have read that **The Dominated Convergence Theorem:** If $\left\{f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\right\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions which converge pointwise almost everywhere to $f,$ and if there exists an integrable function $g$ such that $\left|f_{n}(x)\right| \leq g(x)$ for all $n$ and for all $x,$ then $f$ is integrable and
$$\int \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_{n}$$

Can anybody explain it with better example and also with a counter one. Basically I am getting confused where can I use it ,or where i can't? 
Also I have read this statement:**things can go wrong if a sequence $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ is not dominated by any function.** What is the significance of this?

Comment: Consider for example $f_n(x)=n 1_{[0,1]}(x)$ to get some intuition. You find that there is no integrable dominating function because $\sup_n f_n(x)$ is basically $1/x$. This explains why the limit of the integrals is 1 even though the a.e. point wise limit is the zero function.

Comment: So to use this theorem you need to furnish a dominating function. This can be more art than science sometimes.

Comment: @Ian And moreover I have to integrate that dominate function over  that particular range to chase the  answer.Am i correct?

Comment: No, you just need to know it's integrable.

Answer (score 1):

What goes wrong is that even if $f_n$ does converge point wise to some limit function $f$, the limit $f$ need not be integrable, and so there is no sense in which you can write $\int f=\int \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$.

In fact, the deep point of the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem is that if $f_n$ are dominated by an integrable function, then a pointwise limit, provided it exists, is necessarily integrable. (This does not hold for Riemann integrals, which is why we don't have a dominated convergence theorem for Riemann integrals). The fact that the sequence of integrals converges "to the correct integral" is a result of this.

Comment: You can reasonably write $\int f = \int \lim f_n$; either both sides exist and are equal or neither side exists. The problem is writing $\int f = \lim \int f_n$.